# Timber-timber joists joined in an unusual way?

Tags: framing, joists, uk

I have an upstairs room that I am renovating in a loft-converted house, having recently moved in (UK). The house is from the 1950s, and was originally a 1-story house without the loft. It was upgraded about 20 years ago, adding the extra storey.

I've lifted some floorboards in an upstairs area we are re-carpeting as the floor is super-squeaky, and was unsure if there is an issue with the joists. Looking at the joists, there are two parallel joists that have nails joining each pair of joists. The joists themselves only meet one-another for a short span, and the joist on the left of each pair terminates just under the wall
[image: Joists from above][image: nails in joists]
It looks like the only thing that would stop the joists from pivoting is any cantilever behaviour, as well as just the nails holding the joists together.

Is this a normal design? I'm surprised to not see heavy-duty bolts or metal strapping holding these together. I had a quick look online for building codes, but I was not able to readily decipher the requirements.

As a size reference, the larger heating pipes are 22mm diameter.

Edit : I don't think there is a supporting wall under the join, but am not 100% certain.
Edit 2: Having cleaned a little under the wall, there is a cross-beam that the joint sits on, but only about 5cm worth of the joists that go into the room - its not the full width of the join

Comment: Is there a support beam under those joints?  If so that is good.  If not, not so good.

Comment: Without ripping out the plasterboard, I think it is just plasterboard under the joints

Comment: A beam would show, they are usually as big or bigger than joists and under the joists.  A wall under either of the two ends of those joists will work also, either under those white pipes or the right end of those copper pipes.

Comment: If there is _only_ ceiling below where these joints are, then no, this _most likely_ does not meet building codes. If there is a wall below these joints, then you're most likely just fine. How far to the right do the "upper" (in the picture) boards continue? You indicate a "short span", but that's not a very precise number.

Comment: Having seen your updates: How tall is this 5cm wide beam under the joint? How far (wall-to-wall) does this beam span? The fact that it's only 5cm, in-and-of-itself, isn't a _significant_ issue, the strength of the beam supporting these joints is in the beam's height and the distance of its clear span below (distance between supporting points below).

Comment: Additionally, you may want to check your local building codes for notching of the joists. Any notch will weaken the joist's carrying capacity so there are rules about what percentage of a joist can be notched. For the US, I believe it's no more than 20-25% of the depth of the joist (don't quote me on that). It's probably similar in the UK, but it's important for you to check your local codes to be sure.

Comment: The beam could be up to 2’ away from the splice or sistered joists, I say 2’ because that is what was allowed for a similar add to a cabin we added another bedroom. I remember the cantilever could not exceed 24”. West Coast central oregon.

Comment: @EdBeal  Think I would prefer a support wall/beam under a plain nailed joint if weight bearing floor joists.  Be okay with for non weight bearing ceiling joists.

Comment: @crip659 I was not stating a preference but what code allows and the op could verify as there should be some support from the comments the OP was not sure if there was a wall below , my comment was to point out it could be up to 2’ back and meet code in my jurisdiction.